# Question about some notation in Neukirch( $[a]_F(X)$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

So in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory book, page 343, he defines a formal o-module as:

A formal group $F$ over $O$ together with a ring homomorphism $O\to End_o(F), a\mapsto[a]_F(X)$, such that $[a]_F(X) = aX \mod{\deg 2}$

How is $[a]_F(X)$ defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that an endomorphism of a formal group $F$ over $\mathcal{O}$ is simply a power series $f\in\mathcal{O}[\![X]\!]$ such that $f(F(X,Y)) = F(f(X),f(Y))$. Then a formal $\mathcal{O}$-module is the data of a formal group $F\in\mathcal{O}[\![X,Y]\!]$ together with a ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}\to\operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{O}}(F)$ such that some condition is satisfied.

$[a]_F(X)$ is simply the notation of the image in $\operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{O}}(F)$ of $a\in\mathcal{O}$, and we require that it satisfy $[a]_F(X)\equiv aX\pmod{\deg 2}$. So $[a]_F(X)$ is a power series with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}$ such that there is no degree $0$ term and such that the coefficient of $X$ is $a\in\mathcal{O}$. There is not a specific definition given for $[a]_F(X)$, because we want to be able to consider potentially different formal $\mathcal{O}$-modules. That is, if $F$ and $G$ are two formal $\mathcal{O}$-modules, and $a\in\mathcal{O}$, it need not be true that $[a]_F(X) = [a]_G(X)$.

Comment: Oh I see, so he basically defined it in the statement. A follow up question then is why do we have the requirement that it equals aX (mod deg 2)?

Comment: You can define a formal group over $A$ as a group object in the category of formal lie varieties over $A$ (see [here](http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/FRGLecture.pdf) for details), and then a formal module (over an $A$-algebra $R$) becomes a formal group $F$ together with a ring homomorphism $R\to\operatorname{End}F$ whose derivative $R\to\operatorname{End}\operatorname{Lie}F = A$ is the structure map $R\to A$. The (natural) structure map $A\to A$ is the identity, so that's where that's coming from. Admittedly, this only raises the question of why you want the derivative to be the ct'd

Comment: ct'd structure map, but I don't really have a great answer to this, except that you want some sort of "compatibility" condition as an object over $A$ here, and that's kind of an obvious condition that pops out. There's probably a better answer, but I'll admit that I don't know it off the top of my head.